# Rails engine doesn't load mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I'm working on an engine inside my app and creating a mailer for this engine inside `engines/MY_ENGINE/app/mailers` but I'm getting `uninitialized constant MY_ENGINE::TicketMailer`.

Checking the loaded paths by doing `puts $:` I see rails loads Assets, controllers, models and helpers inside the app folder but not the mailers.

Is there a way to fix this and add a path to be loaded?

Comment: Are you sure your mailer is namespaced like that?

Comment: Yes. It's inside the module MY_ENGINE and it's called TicketMailer. I printed the loaded paths and the mailers folder isn't there. Even if I misspelled the name of the class the folder should be loaded.

Comment: If your module name is *literally* `MY_ENGINE` you're going to have problems. The Rails auto-loader will expand that to something like  `m_y_en_g_i_n_e` which isn't what you want at all. In the auto-loader system `example_name` becomes `ExampleName`. It's best to use a name like `MyEngine` and a path of `my_engine` to be consistent.

Comment: @tadman thank you for your interest, but is not a naming problem, my engine is not named like that, you can see how I solved the problem on my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem. Apparently the mailers folder is not loaded automatically but you can add folders to the load path manually adding a line like this one to your `engine.rb`:

```
paths['app/mailers'] << 'MY_ENGINE/app/mailers'
```

Like this:

```
module MY_ENGINE
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MY_ENGINE
    paths['app/mailers'] << 'MY_ENGINE/app/mailers'
  end
end
```

That fixed the problem.